# Identifying the Zeros of a Polar Graph by Visual Inspection

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

Given a polar graph like the ones below, is there a way to determine at which angle(s) these polar functions have roots/zeros through visual inspection alone? If not, is there a way to determine how many roots the function has from visual inspection alone?
[image: a)]

[image: b)]

Comment: The roots are where $r=0$ but we might not know whether a loop goes through an angle of $\frac{\pi}{2}$ or $\pi$, for example.

Comment: @JohnDouma Is it possible to identify the number of roots from the graph though?

Comment: In your four leaf clover, are there four roots or eight?